# Finding the critical region of conditional exponential probability

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, hypothesis-testing

$X$ is a random variable and its PDF is:

$$
  f(x;θ) = \begin{cases} θe^{-θx}, & x > 0 \\\ 0, & x \le 0 \end{cases}
$$

With a constant $θ_0 > 0$:

$$ 
  H_0: θ = θ_0 \\\ 
  H_1: θ < θ_0
$$

with significant level $\alpha \quad (0 < \alpha < 1)$.

Now, with a constant $d$, $Y$ is a random variable based on $X > d$.

That is to say, for every $y > d, P(Y > y) = P(X > y | X > d)$. Set $b' > d$, when $Y > b'$, we will reject $H_0$.

To find the constant $b'$ which is the reject region value in this case, and based on the memoryless of the exponential distribution, I tried to write:

$$
  P(Y > y) = P(X > y | X > d) = P(X > y - d + d| X > d) = P(X > y - d)
$$

Typically, with left-side testing, I would write:

$$
  \dfrac{b' - θ}{\sqrt{1/θ^2n}} = -ϕ^{-1}(\alpha)
$$

Yet, I am not sure how to do such a similar step on a conditional probability.